# Removing worms from potting soil?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, potting-soil

This is the background for my question...

I had a plant that I bought from a supermarket some time ago. I noticed it was dying, so when I inspected it I noticed the soil had worms (I recently posted a [question about this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47228/is-this-soil-any-good)).

So I took the plant, washed it really well (ie removed all the soil with water) and moved it to another planter with fresh potting soil.

I continue monitoring the plant for several weeks and I notice that it’s still not improving. I remove the plant again and notice that the trunk has small worms inside of it.

My concern is that the potting soil has been contaminated with these worms.

My question: is there a way to make sure that the potting soil isn’t infected with these worms?

Comment: Is this the same plant as in your other recent question? The only thing to add to that answer is that you seem to have two types of "worms". The worms in the pictures in your other thread are earthworms. The "worms in your tree trunk" are most likely some species of insect, or insect larvae. Earthworms don't live in dying tree trunks.

Comment: I don’t know what type of worm it is, but I know they’re not from the potting soil. I want to make sure that I can use this potting soil without worrying that it has worms.

Comment: Try sterilizing the soil in the microwave oven, and wash the roots again...